# elasticsearch nested query, more than one one object should meet conditions

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have some questions about nested query.
Here is my example. The mapping is `{"user":"nested"}`.The exist data just like this:

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "first":"John",
      "last":"Smith"
    },
    {
      "first":"Alice",
      "last":"White"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I create a query to find this document that meets all the conditions:

1. the first object of user that its "first" is "John" and "last" is "Smith";
2. the second object of user that its "first" is "Alice" and "last" is "White"

Comment: Is the order important or you are just looking to retrieve all documents having `John Smith` and `Alice White` ?

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't care the oeder and just want to looking to retrieve all document having John Smith and Alice White.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below query :

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "must":[  
                     {  
                        "bool":{  
                           "must":[  
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "query":{  
                                       "bool":{  
                                          "must":[  
                                             {  
                                                "match_phrase":{  
                                                   "user.first":{  
                                                      "query":"John"
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             },
                                             {  
                                                "match_phrase":{  
                                                   "user.last":{  
                                                      "query":"Smith"
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    },
                                    "path":"user"
                                 }
                              },
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "query":{  
                                       "bool":{  
                                          "must":[  
                                             {  
                                                "match_phrase":{  
                                                   "user.first":{  
                                                      "query":"Alice"
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             },
                                             {  
                                                "match_phrase":{  
                                                   "user.last":{  
                                                      "query":"White"
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    },
                                    "path":"user"
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @MrWong You might want to use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to know more about vote on it or accept it when someone answers.

Answer (score 1):

Below query is what you are looking for. You simply need to have two `nested queries`, one for each conditions you've mentioned, combined in a `bool` using `must` clause.

Note that I'm assuming that the fields `user.first` and `user.last` are of text `type` having `standard analyzer`

```
POST <your_index_name>
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"user",
                  "query":{  
                     "bool":{  
                        "must":[  
                           {  
                              "match":{  
                                 "user.first":"john"
                              }
                           },
                           {  
                              "match":{  
                                 "user.last":"smith"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"user",
                  "query":{  
                     "bool":{  
                        "must":[  
                           {  
                              "match":{  
                                 "user.first":"alice"
                              }
                           },
                           {  
                              "match":{  
                                 "user.last":"white"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah,it works ,thanks.When I change the data to like this{
  "user": [
    {
      "first":"John",
      "last":"100"
    },
    {
      "first":"Alice",
      "last":"200"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @MrWong I've added lowercase in my queries because, I mentioned in the answer, that if you use standard analyzer, the elasticsearch would lowercase the data and save it in inverted index. Hence, even if you make use of lowercase values like `john`, the results would be returned. You can check this link for more info https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

Comment: Regardless, I'm glad that your query has been solved. Feel free to accept the answer and/or upvote it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "has_parent": {
                        "parent_type": "doc",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "id": [
                                                713
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "created": {
                                                "lte": "now/d"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "expires": {
                                                "gte": "now/d"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "prices",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "filter": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "prices.id_prcknd": 167
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "doc_type": "item"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "have_prices": true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "is_folder": true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "folder"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "is_folder": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "title_low.order": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 1000
}
```